# Roll matrix with all possible shifts

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a function that takes in a `(h, w)` matrix and produces an order-3 tensor that for each row contains all possible shifts of size `c` of that row. Here is the function and a usage example

```py
def slow_matrix_roll(v, c):
    h, w = v.shape

    v = np.pad(v, ((0, 0), (0, w - 1)), mode="constant")
    res = np.zeros((h, w, c))

    for j in range(w):
        res[:, j, :] = v[:, j:j+c]

    return res 

inp = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3, 3)
res = slow_matrix_roll(inp, 2)

print(res.shape)
print(res)
```

Input:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Output:

```
(3, 3, 2)
[[[1. 2.]
  [2. 3.]
  [3. 0.]]

 [[4. 5.]
  [5. 6.]
  [6. 0.]]

 [[7. 8.]
  [8. 9.]
  [9. 0.]]]
```

So for example, the first row of the input `[1, 2, 3]` with `c = 2` yields a matrix

```
1 2
2 3
3 0
```

and this happens for each row, resulting in a tensor.

**My question is, how to make this faster?** I guess ideally, I would like to get rid of the for loop, but any faster solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stride_tricks`.

```
def fast_roll(v, c):
    *h, w = v.shape
    V = np.zeros((*h, w+c-1), v.dtype)
    V[..., :w] = v
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(V, (*h, w, c), (*V.strides, V.strides[-1]))
```

Please note that this creates a non-contiguous view. Make a contiguous copy if needed.

Example:

```
>>> fast_roll(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3), 2)
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 0]],

       [[3, 4],
        [4, 5],
        [5, 0]],

       [[6, 7],
        [7, 8],
        [8, 0]]])
```

Comment: I'm trying to extend your solution to support a leading batch dimension for which `fast_roll` should be applied identically. I have trouble understanding what your code, specifically, `as_strided` in this case does. Would it be possible to add a brief explanation?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but `as_strided` creates a view from a data buffer, a shape and a strides tuple. The roll is implemented by using the last stride twice. The effect of that is that moving one element along the last or last but one axes both move one step in the data buffer. HTH